# Space fighter fakes being a hero book

Tags: story-identification

I'm not sure if it was a shortish book or a novelette in an anthology, I read it in the UK about 2000.

There's a war going on between Earth colonised space and the alien menace, the main protagonist is out in his one-man fighter on routine patrol in a remote sector, then his scanners pick up an alien dreadnought, he yells for help on his FTL communicator and then dives in to attack with guns blazing and missiles firing.

When the squadron arrives they see a destroyed battleship with his craft buzzing around it, he's still pressing fire buttons but his magazines are empty.  He's feted as a hero and given the top medal, now he can basically do what he wants.

He's eating in fancy places for free, if he wants a new car the dealers compete to donate their finest machines for the prestige. If he fancies a gorgeous married woman their husband bows and allows it, the woman gladly donates herself to his fun.

It transpires it's a fraud, Mr unscrupulous businessman stumbled across the derelict craft and hatched a plot, then worked through lots of files to find the right pilot who would play along and fake an attack. The businessmen can then use hero's influence for nefarious schemes.

Eventually the pilot takes a brave step, he arranges a private meet with Terran president and confesses all, the president sorts all by getting something (I can't remember) to happen to bad businessman.
He then tells fighter pilot that Earth needs military heroes so he'll have to play the role for life.

Comment: There is a similar book by Ben "Yahtzee" Croshaw, that is called "Will save galaxy for food". But there are too many differences for it to be the case. Space fighter pilot = check. Pretending to be legend= check. Unscrupulous businessman = check. Fake attack by aliens= check. But the plot is different, with unscrupulous businessman hiring the nobody pilot to pretend to be a legendary one so he can take businessman's son to space ride, because son is a huge fan of legendary pilot.

Comment: Vaguely reminiscent of *Galactic Medal of Valor* by Mack Reynolds but I don't have the details to hand.

Comment: @Paulie_D  I've downloaded that book and it is indeed the one I was seeking - please post as an answer and I'll accept: cheers

Comment: Yes this is Galactic Medal of Valor by Mack Reynolds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### *Galactic Medal of Honor* by Mack Reynolds

A blurb from Fantastic Fiction

> It was the highest and most coveted award of all time. It was given to only the bravest among those defending Earth from the mysterious Kradens. Many had sacrificed their lives for it. The current bearer of the medal became the idol of all mankind - a man above the law, a man who would never want for anything. One man was going to cheat to win it - and live to regret it.

This was an expanded version of *Medal of Honor*, appearing in *Amazing*, Nov. 1960

Comment: You're sure it's "Valor" and not "Honor?"  I only find "[Galactic Medal of Honor](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?28735)" listed on ISFDb.  It's also a full novel, only printed standalone, not matching an anthology entry.

Comment: Answer updated. The base story was expanded from a short story to a longer novel.

Comment: I think, based on the amount (and specifics) of plot in the description that this is actually the short story "[Medal of Honor](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?81633)" on which *Galactic Medal of Honor* was based.  It was published in *Amazing*, November 1960, anthologized in [*Space-Fighters*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?31492) (1988).